# Enchanter adaptation of the Nightmare Spinner prestige class

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

The *Complete Mage* prestige class *Nightmare Spinner* has the following adaptation entry:

> The nightmare spinner class is designed as an illusion specialist, but
> it could work just as well with an enchantment specialty, since most
> spells from that school are also mindaffecting. Such a character
> probably would not have an evil bent, and the class abilities could be
> modified to allow him to charm or dominate creatures that are usually
> immune to such spells.

*(Complete Mage, p. 74)*

As a player of a wizard character who specialized in the school of enchantment I find the prospect of being able to *„charm or dominate creatures that are usually immune to such spells“* very interesting.
How could an adequate and balanced adaptation of this class look like? What class features would be appropriate? I already found suggestions [here](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=8047.0#top) and [here](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?189346-3-5-PrC-Charmer-(Nightmare-Spinner-adaptation)-PEACH) but I still would appreciate an answer on this site very much.

Comment: What's strange about the nightmare spinner prestige class's Adaptation entry is that, while "the class abilities could be modified to allow him to charm or dominate creatures that are usually immune to such spells," the nightmare spinner prestige class itself doesn't actually offer class features that enable a spinner to affect with fear effects creatures that are immune to fear effects. This means any answer's adaptation will be less "adapted" and, instead, just simply made up. Usually, a forum is a better venue for homebrew material.